# create a lot of svg's with php

Tags: php, svg, mamp

I try to load a simple text file where each line has a name and create svg's out of those names. It doesn't matter for now if those svg's are empty, i'm more interested in getting the file.

I use MAMP at the moment on a mac. If i run this script, then i don't see any files appearing. Am i doing something wrong or am I looking in the wrong direction?
If I load the file I do see a error but it appear's to quick for me to read.

Please help.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$codes = file('someFile.txt');


foreach ($codes as $code) {

    ob_start();


echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="2075px" height="775px" viewBox="0 0 2075 775" enable-background="new 0 0 2075 775" xml:space="preserve">

<?php

    }

?>
</svg>
<?php 

    file_put_contents("out/$code.svg", ob_get_clean());

}

?>
```

Comment: If you echo the output buffer (or disable output buffering), what do you get? Also, have you checked the result of `file_put_contents`? If it ` === false`, then there was an error writing the file.

Comment: thanks. `file_put_contents` returns false indeed.
I'm trying to fix that now but it ain't easy.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues:

`$codes` should be an `array`, since you are trying to use it in a `foreach` loop. The next issue is minor, and that is you have one too many closing brackets `}`. This can be resolved by eliminating the intermediate `<?php` code you have:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$codes = array('someFile','someFile2');

foreach ($codes as $code) {
    ob_start();

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="2075px" height="775px" viewBox="0 0 2075 775" enable-background="new 0 0 2075 775" xml:space="preserve">
</svg>

<?php
    file_put_contents("/out/".$code.".svg", ob_get_clean());
}   
?>
```

Comment: `$codes` is an array by me, `$codes = file('someFile.txt');
echo sizeof($codes);` However, if i run your code, I still don't see any file created. Should it be created where the php file is or will it be created somewhere else on the HD like a tmp folder?